# Lisp: How to stop unwanted reassignment of multiple list variables

Tags: list, variables, lisp, common-lisp

In lisp, I have the following example code:

```
(setf list1 '("a" "b" "c" )) 
(setf list2 '())
(setf list2 list1)
(setf (nth 2 list1) "d")
(princ list1)
(princ list2)
```

I want the result to be:

```
(a b d)(a b c)
```

but it instead reassigns the nth element of both 'list1' AND 'list2', resulting in:

```
(a b d)(a b d)
```

I'm assuming it's because I set list2 equal to list1 earlier in the code, but usually when you set variables equal to one another, they don't change like that. What's going on here?

Comment: **I'm assuming it's because I set list2 equal to list1 earlier in the code, but usually when you set variables equal to one another, they don't change like that.** Can you explain what you mean here? Aside from one language I can think of with operator overloading, assigning the same value to two variables would exhibit this type of behavior. E.g., in java, after doing `List <Integer> b = a; b.add (2);` you'll see 2 in "both" lists (there is only one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign lists in lisp, no copying happens.  The third line from your question:

```
(setf list2 list1)
```

does not copy the list, but rather sets list2 to also refer to the same cons cell as list1.  If you want a fresh list, instead use [copy-list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm):

```
(setf list2 (copy-list list1))
```

Which will set list2 to be a shallow copy of list1; that is to say that all the CARs of the CONS cells in list1 and list2 will be the [same](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#same).

Comment: Didn't know about `copy-list`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case no one is able to help me, I came up with a solution to override the issue, although it's not very elegant:

```
(setq list1 '("a" "b" "c")) 
(setq list2 '())
(setq i 0) 
(loop 
(setf list2 (append list2'(0)))
(setf (nth i list2)(nth i list1))
(setq i (+ i 1))
(when (= i (list-length list1)) (return)))
(setf (nth 2 list1) "d")
(princ list1)
(princ list2)
```

Still very curious why `(setf (nth N L) T)` resets the nth element of all lists whose values have been equated using `set`.